# Alamofire request not running completion block inside NSOperation

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, alamofire, nsoperation

`Note`: While there are other, similar questions to this one in SO, in none of them the authors seem to be controlling the lifecycle of the `Operation` by themselves. Please, read through before referring to another question.

I created an [NS]Operation in Swift 3.0 to download, parse and cache some data in Core Data.

At first, I used the `main()` method in the Operation to execute the task at hand and it worked well. Now I need to run several separate tasks to retrieve information about each/every device I got in this step. For this, I need to ensure that the devices are actually in Core Data before I attempt to get the other information. For that reason, I want to make sure that I decide when the task is complete -- which is when ALL the devices are safe and sound in the cache -- before firing the dependent requests.

The problem is that even though I have checked that Alamofire does execute the request and the server does send the data, the completion block marked with the comment [`THIS WONT EXECUTE!`] is never executed. This causes the Queue to stall, since the Operation is marked as `finished` inside the said completion block, which is the desired behavior.

Does anyone has any ideas about what might be going on here?

```
class FetchDevices: Operation {

    var container: NSPersistentContainer!
    var alamofireManager: Alamofire.SessionManager!
    var host: String!
    var port: Int!

    private var _executing = false
    private var _finished = false

    override internal(set) var isExecuting: Bool {
        get {
            return _executing
        }

        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
            _executing = newValue
            didChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
        }
    }

    override internal(set) var isFinished: Bool {
        get {
            return _finished
        }

        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
            _finished = newValue
            didChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
        }
    }

    override var isAsynchronous: Bool {
        return true
    }

    init(usingContainer container: NSPersistentContainer, usingHost host: String, usingPort port: Int) {
        super.init()

        self.container = container
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10 // in seconds
        self.alamofireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    }

    override func start() {
        if self.isCancelled {
            self.isFinished = true
            return
        }

        self.isExecuting = true

        alamofireManager!.request("http://apiurlfor.devices")
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                // THIS WONT EXECUTE!
                if self.isCancelled {
                    self.isExecuting = false
                    self.isFinished = true
                    return
                }

                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    let jsonData = JSON(value)

                    self.container.performBackgroundTask { context in
                        for (_, rawDevice):(String, JSON) in jsonData {
                            let _ = Device(fromJSON: rawDevice, usingContext: context)
                        }

                        do {
                            try context.save()
                        } catch {
                            let saveError = error as NSError
                            print("\(saveError), \(saveError.userInfo)")
                        }

                        self.isExecuting = false
                        self.isFinished = true
                    }

                case .failure(let error):
                    print("May Day! May Day! \(error)")
                    self.isExecuting = false
                    self.isFinished = true
                }
        }
    }
}
```

A piece of information that may be useful is that in the method where I queue all the operations, I use `queue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()` to execute a completion handler after all is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have something else that is blocking the main thread, which `responseJSON` uses for its closure, resulting in a deadlock. You can confirm this quickly replacing `responseJSON` with `.responseJSON(queue: .global())` to have Alamofire use a queue other than the main queue, and you will see this behavior change. But if you do this (for diagnostic purposes only), you should change it back and then turn your attention to identify and eliminate whatever is blocking the main thread (i.e. don't wait on the main thread), as you should never block the main thread.

---

You mention that you are calling `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished`. While that is an intoxicatingly simple solution for waiting for a series of operations to finish, you should never do that from the main thread. The main thread should never be blocked (or, at least, not for more than a few milliseconds). It can result in a substandard UX (where the app freezes) and your app is susceptible to being summarily terminated by the "watch dog" process. I suspect that one of the reasons that the Alamofire author(s) felt so comfortable dispatching their completion handlers to the main queue by default is that not only is it often useful and convenient, but they know one would never block the main thread.

When using operation queues, the typical pattern to avoid ever waiting is to use a completion operation:

```
let completionOperation = BlockOperation {
    // something that we'll do when all the operations are done
}

for object in arrayOfObjects {
    let networkOperation = ...
    completionOperation.addDependency(networkOperation)
    queue.addOperation(networkOperation)
}

OperationQueue.main.addOperation(completionOperation)
```

You can achieve something similar if you use dispatch groups and dispatch group "notify" (though, typically, if you're using operation queues, you'd generally stay within the operation queue paradigm, for consistency's sake).

If you want to call `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished`, technically you can do that, but you should only do that if you dispatch that "wait" to some background queue (e.g. a global queue, but obviously not to your own operation queue upon which you added all of these operations). I think this is a wasteful pattern, though (why tie up some global worker thread waiting for operations to finish when you have a perfectly good mechanism for specifying a completion operation).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer @Rob. I did what you suggested and there was no change. I will take a look at the `blocking the main thread` thing, but I don't see what can be causing that. The code that you see is the whole Operation.There isn't more to it.

Comment: OK @Rob, I think you pointed in the right direction, but there is still more work to be done. I am using `queue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()`, in the method that is in charge of queuing the tasks. If I comment that, the queue won't stall, but I actually need to wait for all the Operations to finish before I call a completion handler. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Your answer sent me in the right direction in the end. I just edited it to add a link to a question that addresses the original problem, which I only found after analyzing the issue taking into account your pointers.

Comment: That link, showing you how to use a queue other than the main queue, is what I tried to describe above. But my point is that this is _not_ a good solution, but rather it's merely a useful diagnostic to confirm the presence of this deeper problem, namely that you're blocking the main thread with that "wait". But, you should  _never_  `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` from the main queue. If you want to do something when all of your operations are done, create a "completion" operation, and add dependencies between all of your other operations and this dependency operation. But never "wait".

Comment: Uhhhmm, that makes sense, though it can get messy as the number of tasks increases. Do you want to explain more in depth, since you took the link down? I think that your answer deserves to be selected, but it is only half useful as it is now, if people still have to go hunting for clarity elsewhere.

Comment: If you want, you can actually post your own answer to your question (I know, it seems odd, but it's a practice that is [encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) and others can vote on it, if they think it's worthwhile. But, to be clear, it's always a mistake to block the main thread and by moving the completion closures to some background queue that merely treats the symptoms (the deadlock), not the disease (the fact that you're waiting on the main thread). I tried to expand/clarify above, as well as discuss a few options.

Comment: I think your answer is more complete now and it is still the right answer. I did it as suggested and it is working like charm. Thanks for putting in the effort.